# Summation bounds for the following problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

**Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{{n-1 \choose k-1}}{k}\right)$**

Now the way I solved this was by multiplying by n and turning it into

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk$

my mistake was that I took the summation when $k=0$ to give me an easy $2^{n}$ which I divide by n to get a final answer of

${2^{n} \over n}$ when it is actually supposed to be ${2^{n} -1 \over n}$

My question is how would I find that changing $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk$ to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk$ would change the numerator to ${2^{n} -1}$.

Comment: You seem to be missing a factor $\tfrac1n$ in your summations.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the bottom index simply omits the first term in the sum, which is $\binom{n}{0}=1$. So
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk-1.$$

Comment: alright so since it omits the first term which is equal to 1, i would just subtract 1 from the summation. That make sense. Now sorry if this is a really obvious question, but I am completely new to this, $\binom{n}{0}=1$ is this from pascals triangle? or is just whenever you "choose" 0 its always equal to 1?

Comment: There are many ways to see it, and what is the easiest way depends on your definition. You could read it off from Pascals triangle; these are all the $1$'s at the beginning of every row. Or from the combinatiorial interpretation; there is precisely $1$ way to choose nothing from $n$ elements. Or algebraically
$$\binom n0=\frac{n!}{0!n!}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t it just that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n c_k=c_0 +\sum_{k=1}^n c_k$$
and noting that your $c_0=1$?